# Select specific element with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to select title with CSS selector.
This is my css

```css
.category-center :nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-center">
  <div class="cbp-item-wrapper">
    <div class="post-medias">
      <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="#" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-info">
      <h4 class="post-title">
        <a href="" target="_blank">This is awesome title</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Why don't you just target `<h4>` here?

Comment: Target it with 'post-title' class.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Category class ("category-center") must be included in this task. I now that I can select just h4 but Im trying to select title from <div class="category-center">

Comment: Well then use `.category-center h4` or `.category-center .post-title`, if your actual goal is to only format titles within a parent with that class…?

Comment: @jomskris as a tip for the future, paste your html/css into vscode and run the format document command before adding to your question so it's readable :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.category-center .post-title a`. It will target the `<a>` element which is inside the element with class `post-title` which is inside `category-center` element.

You could even use `.post-title a` but it will break the hierarchy of CSS which you already have for elements inside `.category-center`. Also, it will tightly bound the HTML with CSS so when in future if you place the HTML outside of `.category-center` then the styles will not apply and you will know that something is going wrong with that action.

```css
.category-center .post-title a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-center">
  <div class="cbp-item-wrapper">
    <div class="post-medias">
      <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="#" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-info">
      <h4 class="post-title"><a href="" target="_blank">This is awesome title</a></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="cbp-item-wrapper">
    <div class="post-medias">
      <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="#" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-info">
      <h4 class="post-title"><a href="" target="_blank">This is awesome title</a></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="cbp-item-wrapper">
    <div class="post-medias">
      <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="#" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-info">
      <h4 class="post-title"><a href="" target="_blank">This is awesome title</a></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just target the class rather than going specific numnber of children in, as this means if you change your page redesign slightly, it will no longer work.

You can either put a class on your a tag, or target any a tag, on your h4 class, as below.

```css
.post-title a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-center">
  <div class="cbp-item-wrapper">
    <div class="post-medias">
      <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="#" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-info">
      <h4 class="post-title"><a href="" target="_blank">This is awesome title</a></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```